# Are fixed-term research funded staff such as post-docs entitled to redundancy rights, such as severence pay at end of contract?

Tags: postdocs, united-kingdom

According to [Fixed-term employment contracts](https://www.gov.uk/fixed-term-contracts/employees-rights) at gov.uk:

> Anyone who’s worked continually for the same employer for 2 years or more has the same [redundancy rights](https://www.gov.uk/redundant-your-rights) as a permanent employee.

When [ending a fixed-term contract](https://www.gov.uk/fixed-term-contracts/renewing-or-ending-a-fixedterm-contract) specifically:

> If a contract isn't renewed, this is considered to be a dismissal, and if the employee has 2 years’ service the employer needs to show that there’s a ‘fair’ reason for not renewing the contract.

Redundancy rights [include](https://www.gov.uk/redundant-your-rights) redundancy pay and a notice period, among other things.

Do those redundancy rights apply for research funded staff on fixed term employment contracts at universities in England?  My question covers both postdocs (Grade 6) and other research funded staff (Grade 7).

(There are also other rights, such as *Any employee on fixed-term contracts for 4 or more years will automatically become a permanent employee*, but those come with caveats already on the gov.uk page; my question is specifically about redundancy rights)

---

**Edit:** It appears this may depend on whether postdocs are legally considered [trainees on a work-experience placement](https://www.gov.uk/fixed-term-contracts/what-counts-as-a-fixedterm-contract) or not.  Since my question covers both postdocs and other research funded staff, the trainee-or-not status of postdocs would need to be established in order to answer the overall question.

Comment: "Workers don’t count as fixed-term employees if they: ...are a...trainee on a work-experience placement" (source: https://www.gov.uk/fixed-term-contracts/what-counts-as-a-fixedterm-contract). So post-docs might not be considered fixed-term employees. Hence, would not be entitled severance pay.

Comment: You might want to clarify whether you are considering trainees or non-trainees, because the answer will differ.

Comment: @user2768 I have no clue whether postdocs in the UK are legally considered "trainees on a work-experience placement".  Certainly my employer does not describe me as such in my employment contract.

Comment: I don't know whether "trainee" is legally defined in the UK, but definitions of postdoc include the word training, e.g., "[a] postdoc is a person...who is pursuing additional research, training, or teaching in order to have better skills to pursue a career in academia, research, or any other fields" -- https://postdocs.cornell.edu/structure-postdoctoral-study

Comment: @user2768 But they're also employees, and your link is from New York, USA.  There must be many precedents of postdocs leaving employment at end of contract after >2 years in the UK that can inform an answer to my question.

Comment: The definition is from a prestigious academic institution and I believe it will be accepted internationally, by academics at least. Regarding the "many...postdocs leaving employment at end of contract after >2 years in the UK," I am sure there are. But, those that didn't receive any severance pay can't help you. (They may not have insisted that their employer's obligations were fulfilled.) And any that did might not be able to help either. (They may have had a different contract.) In any case, your question relates to UK law, rather than whether particular postdocs received severance.

Comment: Try contacting the Citizens Advice Bureaux.

Comment: @user2768 I have contacted the [UCU](https://www.ucu.org.uk/) (where I am a member) with this question, they might know.  See also https://www.ucu.org.uk/legal-dispute-at-stirling and https://www.ucu.org.uk/article/3547/The-ending-of-a-fixed-term-contract---some-information

Comment: the UCU looks like an excellent organisation to contact. Making several assumptions, I presume that you aren't expecting/haven't received severance, when you believe it is legally due. Moving forwards, you should consider whether you want to chase what you believe is legally due. It might well be expensive in terms of your time and finances (a lawyer might be required), and it might well damage your reputation (your supervisor, head of school, dean, ... might be involved and that could be damaging, this could be mitigated if they believe you're right).

Comment: @user2768 My end of contract is only in two years (unless renewed by another fixed-term contract), but it never hurts to know what to expect, so the hypothetical situation of a legal conflict is not currently applicable.  I only learned about those rights outlined at gov.uk recently (see also [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/86864/1033)), so now I'm curious as it would mean the armies of fixed term staff employed by the university may be in a slightly better situation than I thought we were.

Comment: See https://www.ucu.org.uk/article/3547/The-ending-of-a-fixed-term-contract---some-information and specifically "employees with more than 2 years' service are entitled to redundancy".

Comment: I'll tell you this much: They are if the academic staff unions in the UK demand that they are, and stick by this demand. And if that's not the case I'm sure the universities can come up with some legal fantasy they declare to be the truth to avoid paying.

Comment: @user2768 the most common official job title for a postdoc in the UK is "Postdoctoral Research Assistant" or "Postdoctoral Research Associate". Unilke in the US, a postdoc is considered a member of research staff and not generally a trainee (unless on a speicfic "Postdoctoral Training Fellowship").

Many PDRAs don't receive redundancy because they leave to take up a new position before the last day of their old position, but universities do pay up, without argument, if you are still in place on the last day of a contract of more than 2 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you refer to your contract, you will find it is a contract of employment (and probably explicitly states that you are an employee of the university*). Indeed, some universities issue permanent contracts, with a "we'll make you redundant once the funding runs out" clause, to their postdocs.

A few other points:

- If you wanted to claim redundancy benefits, you would have to wait for the university to actually let you go. This prevents you leaving before the end of your contract, so will limit your ability to look for a new job in a timely fashion. The university could just shift you into another role to avoid the redundancy costs (especially if it's one you'll want to leave); although, hopefully, most wouldn't be that cynical.

  - (There's a possibility that they could also require you to apply for suitable, open internal positions, but I don't know whether they could seriously claim your failure to do this equated to leaving voluntarily.)
- From [your own link](https://www.gov.uk/fixed-term-contracts/renewing-or-ending-a-fixedterm-contract), there is no notice period on the non-renewal of a fixed term contract; so a notice period on non-renewal of the contract would only apply to people who, by virtue of over four years of service, have become permanent employees:

  > Fixed-term contracts will normally end automatically when they reach the agreed end date. The employer doesn’t have to give any notice.
- Postdocs are not students or trainees. Here's the definition of those two categories, from the [Fixed-term Employees (Prevention of Less Favourable Treatment) Regulations 2002 (part 5, exclusions)](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2002/2034/part/5) (emphasis added):

  > 18.—(1) These Regulations shall not have effect in relation to a fixed-term employee who is employed on a scheme, **designed to provide him with training or work experience for the purpose of assisting him to seek or obtain work**...
  >
  > [cut, funding info]
  >
  > (2) These Regulations shall not have effect in relation to a fixed-term employee whose employment consists in attending **a period of work experience not exceeding one year that he is required to attend as part of a higher education course**....
  >
  > [cut, references to the acts that define a HE course]
- The pay grade is irrelevant.

*Weirdly, I have seen employment contracts that state you're not (and not for self-employed contracting arrangements). I don't know why because a court wouldn't find someone not to be an employee just because the contract says so.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just like to add 1) Employers are required to offer you internal redeployment opportunities if your services are no longer required. 2) Many universities will offer two levels of redundancy, an enhanced redundancy if you can show if engaged in good faith in the redeployment system and the legal minimum if you don't. Often if you take enhanced redundancy you will be barred from working at that uni for a specified period.